# Auto Start Application through Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I am preparing the app that will run in background.When user restart or reboot his phone than app will start work  automatically.I  am use**Broadcast Receiver** to  receive the **boot completed action**.I receive the  success message in Log-cat to boot completed but app will not start work.I am put user permissions in manifest file and in receiver tag  put action to boot completed.I want to start **Media Projection**  when Boot Completed.But I can't do this.So Please suggest me how its possible in **Broadcast Receiver**.

Comment: please share your manifest code and Intent code to launch an app

Comment: Pretty unclear and contradictory talk. Please try better. And show your code.

Comment: I simply  just do when phone is restart then app is automatically start the work

Comment: Well that is not too difficult. Just show what you have done so far.

Comment: if boot completed then activity or services work start but i want app work start

Comment: please say me any one how to i get Media Projection in broadcast receiver ??